# Average half hourly data into daily data and list it without using the "offset" function

Tags: excel, time-series

I currently have some time-series data in excel.
It is currently in half hourly intervals for a year, however I only want daily data. So I want to average the 48half hours into a day. But doing this manually takes quite a while, and the only other way I can think of doing this is using `OFFSET` however it's really slow on my machine, and still not great.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Let me know if my question doesn't make enough sense.

Thanks
[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbCHz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **pivot table**

Select all of your data, and then click insert, insert pivot table.
In the rows, put 'days' and in the values put 'average of price'.

[image: pivot tables]

Hope this helps!